# What does "go by" and "gap year"

Tags: word-meaning

> Did you move home after University while you hunted for a job? Or stop over at your parents' house a little longer than planned while saving after your **gap year**? You're not alone and no one is judging you, if the latest research is anything to **go by**.

1. What does it mean **be sth to go by** ? Could you write at least one more example,please?
2. What is **gap year** in this context?

Comment: "go by" here means to use (the latest research) as the basis for forming an opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Some people choose to take a [gap year](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gap_year) between high school and college (here, "University"), instead of going to college the fall of the year after graduating from high school. In the context, it is implied that the person stayed with their parents after the end of this time period (and possibly during it, as the first sentence implies).

"Anything to go by" is used here to mean "accurate". In other words,

> You're not alone and no one is judging you, if the latest research is accurate.

This implies that if recent research is correct, others are in the same situation. The research could have taken the form of surveys or polling.

Comment: I would suggest "trust" or "believe" instead of "accurate"